# refresh datagridview from another form

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, refresh

i have two form. main form and child form. in main form show datagridview and in child form is a form to insert data to datagridview in main form.. so after i insert data from child form i want to refresh the datagridview in main form. so the new data appear in datagridview. i tried this code, but the datagridview not refresh, i must close my application and reopen it to show the new datagridview...

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cstr = "server=localhost;User Id=root;database=sma9";
        con1 = new MySqlConnection(cstr);
        con1.Open();
        com1 = new MySqlCommand();
        com1.Connection = con1;
        com1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        com1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbukux (kodebuku,judulbuku,namakategori,pengarang,penerbit,tahunterbit,stokbuku) VALUES ('" + txtkode.Text + "','" + txtjudul.Text + "','" + txtkategori.Text + "','" + txtpengarang.Text + "','" + txtpenerbit.Text + "','" + txttahun.Text + "','" + txtstok.Text + "')";
        com1.ExecuteNonQuery();            
        con1.Close();
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.gridbuku.RefreshEdit();                        
    }
```

i also tried this, but not working too

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        string cstr = "server=localhost;User Id=root;database=sma9";
        con1 = new MySqlConnection(cstr);
        con1.Open();
        com1 = new MySqlCommand();
        com1.Connection = con1;
        com1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        com1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbukux (kodebuku,judulbuku,namakategori,pengarang,penerbit,tahunterbit,stokbuku) VALUES ('" + txtkode.Text + "','" + txtjudul.Text + "','" + txtkategori.Text + "','" + txtpengarang.Text + "','" + txtpenerbit.Text + "','" + txttahun.Text + "','" + txtstok.Text + "')";
        com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        com2 = new MySqlCommand();
        com2.Connection = con1;
        com2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        com2.CommandText = "select * from tbukux";
        ds1 = new DataSet();
        adp1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(com2);
        adp1.Fill(ds1, "tbukux");
        form1.gridbuku.DataSource = ds1;
        form1.gridbuku.DataMember = "tbukux";
        con1.Close();            
        form1.gridbuku.Refresh();                        
    }
```

Comment: try form1.gridbuku.DataSource = null and than assign data source again every time when you need to refresh the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new event like this in frmNewBook

```
public event System.Action NotifyAnotherForm
```

Now put this event in under btnOpenForm_click at your main form

```
frmNewBook form = new frmNewBook();
form.NotifyAnotherForm += new System.Action(mainForm_NotifyAnotherForm);
form.Show(); // or .ShowDialog();
```

At the main form, you must have a method to handle this event

```
public void mainForm_NotifyAnotherForm() {
    //put you code for update datagrid
}
```

When you do some modification in frmNewBook, it will do an event in its proper place

```
if (NotifyAnotherForm != null) {
   NotifyAnotherForm();
}
```

And if you more easy way, you can try do like this

```
frmNewBook form = new frmNewBook();

//You code will pause until form.Show close
form.Show(); // or .ShowDialog();

//After frmNewBook close, code will continue running and you can put code to update
loadDataGrid();
```

I advise you please put you **parameter** in SQL COMMAND to avoid [**Sql Injection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

also you can use "using".

```
      public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       frmChildForm ofrmchild = new frmChildForm();

            using(new frmChildForm())

        {
            ofrmchild .BringToFront();
            ofrmchild .ShowDialog();

        }
         loadDataGrid();  

   }
```